# Grouping & counting records in LINQ to SQL while including all records from count

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

The following LINQ to Entities query gets all link clicks from an email, groups them by URL and projects them into a model.

The desired end result would be something like:

```
Clicks  |  URL     |  Clickers
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          x.com      User 1, User 2...
1          y.com      User 1
```

I have an object `CampaignEmailRecipient` which contains ALL users who clicked the link, which I'd also like to include in my model in property `Clickers`.

I'm just not sure how to do this properly with my group in place and wondered if anybody would be able to assist?

**My model**

```
public class CampaignEmailReportLinksViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CampaignElementId { get; set; }
    public string LinkURL { get; set; }
    public int QtyClicks { get; set; }
    public CampaignEmailRecipient Clickers { get; set; }
}
```

**My query**

```
public List<CampaignEmailReportLinksViewModel> GetCampaignLinksByElementId(int id, int cid, string user)
{
    var items = (from t1 in db.CampaignLinkClicks
                    where
                        (t1.CampaignLink.CampaignElementId == id) &&
                        (t1.CampaignLink.CampaignElement.Campaign.CompanyId == cid)

                    group new {t1} by new
                                        {
                                            t1.CampaignLink.URL,
                                            t1.CampaignLink.CampaignElementId
                                        }
                    into g

                    select new CampaignEmailReportLinksViewModel
                            {
                                LinkURL = g.Key.URL,
                                QtyClicks = g.Count(),
                                Clickers = ???????????
                            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.QtyClicks).ToList();

    return items.ToList();
}
```

***EDIT***

CampaignLinkClick looks like this:

```
public int Id
public int CampaignRecipientId
public string IP
public datetime Timestamp
public int CampaignLinkId
```

Comment: Can you please enumerate all the properties of CampaignLinkClicks?

Comment: @Richthofen I have added this to the end of the question.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so I assume that CampaignRecipientId points to a record that indicates who clicked on it? If you are using EntityFramework and foreign keys, you should be able to use a navigation property on CampaignLinkClick.CampaignRecipients to get those. If you aren't using foreign keys, you'd have to do db.CampaignRecepients.Where(n => n.CampaignRecipientID = t1.CampaignLinkClick.CampaignRecipientID)

Comment: @Richthofen Thanks for your response. Are you able to show me this in context using my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think on what you're trying to do, your SQL will group items by the URL, so if you had:

```
User  |  URL     
--------------------------------------------------
User1          x.com      
User2          x.com      
User1          y.com
```

When you group by URL you will get a result set of and so the sub element of user will be lost, as so,

```
URL     
--------------------------------------------------
x.com      
y.com
```

One (rather costly) way would be to get the results of each URL,

```
select new CampaignEmailReportLinksViewModel
                            {
                                LinkURL = g.Key.URL,
                                QtyClicks = g.Count(),
                                Clickers = ""
                            }

foreach(var item in items){
    item.Clickers = db.CampaignLinkClicks
                           .Where(x=>x.Url == item.URL)
                           .Clickers.Select(x=>x.Name).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess that's exactly my question :) I wondered how to do this in the most succinct way possible.